# Java Performance on Macbook Pro (not GUI)

Tags: java, macos

I have some Java code to fetch data from `SQLite` and do some linguistic processing (lemmatization) with the data and write the modified data into another `SQLite datebase`. The database tables have indexes, so the query should be fast although the data is joined.
The small program shall produce a database being used in an iPhone app.
On my `Ubuntu PC` (14.04.3 LTS) this program runs fast, but on my `Macbook Pro` (OS X El Capitan 10.11) it runs 10 or more times slower.

**java -version on Ubuntu PC:**

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

**java -version on Macbook:**

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

I also pointed eclipse to jdk 7 in `Java->Installed JREs` to have the same version as on the Ubuntu PC

The java command generated by eclipse is the same on both machines:

```
/path/to/jdk7/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath 
... many jars ...
my.package.myclass
```

How to get the same speed on the `Macbook`? Is the java implementation just not that fast under `Mac OS`?

Comment: What are the absolute numbers you're talking about? Is "10 times slower" 1 second instead of 100 milliseconds, or 1 hour instead of 6 minutes?

Comment: The performance of your program depends on more than just the Java version. CPU speed and since you are using a database the speed of your hard drive as well... What are the differences there?

Comment: It's the query and the linguistic processing that takes the time on the Macbook. On Ubuntu Pc one query or linguistic processing takes 0.0x seconds and on Mac OS it takes 0.x to x.x seconds, so actually it's up to 100 times slower! The Macbook CPU should be better. It's an i5. The Ubuntu PC CPU is the weakest i3. The SQLite databases on both machines are on SSD.

Comment: Just managed to run the program in a virtual Ubuntu machine on my Macbook and it runs nearly as fast as on the Ubuntu PC, so it must have something to do with the Oracle Java implementation on Mac OS